# Setting Value for Dynamic ngModel inside ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

How do I set the value of a dynamically created ng-model inside of ng-repeat?

I'm trying to set each dynamic ng-model to `true` or `false`

html file

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="awayTeamPlayer in ulineup.awayTeamPlayersLineup ">
    <md-checkbox ng-model="ulineup.awayTeamPlayersPlayed[awayTeamPlayer.player]"></md-checkbox>
    {{awayTeamPlayer.player}}
</md-list-item>
```

controller file

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('UpdateLineUpController',
                    ['$routeParams', '$firebaseArray', 'FIREBASE_URL',
                    function($routeParams, $firebaseArray, FIREBASE_URL) {

            var vm = this;
            var gameId = $routeParams.gameId;
            var lineupId = $routeParams.lineupId;
            var awayTeamPlayersLineupRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'games/' + gameId + '/lineup/' + lineupId + '/awayTeamPlayersLineup');
            vm.awayTeamPlayersLineup = $firebaseArray(awayTeamPlayersLineupRef);

            // tried the following but that doesn't work
            angular.forEach(vm.awayTeamPlayersLineup, function(value, key) {
                if(value.played === true) {
                    // trying to set ng-model value to true gives me the following error
                    // TypeError: Cannot set property 'Mark' of undefined
                    vm.awayTeamPlayersPlayed[value.player] = true;
                } else {
                    vm.awayTeamPlayersPlayed[value.player] = false;
                }
            });

        }]);

})();
```

Comment: Have you tried using ng-init in the repeat?

Answer (score 0):

Here try using an init to create the property in memory.

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="awayTeamPlayer in ulineup.awayTeamPlayersLineup ">
<md-checkbox ng-init="dynamicProp = 'whatever'" ng-model="ulineup.awayTeamPlayersPlayed[awayTeamPlayer.player]"></md-checkbox>
{{awayTeamPlayer.player}}
</md-list-item>
```

Comment: I've tried `ng-init` and it does not work for me. I tried the following code `<md-checkbox ng-init="ulineup.awayTeamPlayersPlayed[awayTeamPlayer.player] = (awayTeamPlayer.played === 'yes') ? true : false" ng-model="ulineup.awayTeamPlayersPlayed[awayTeamPlayer.player]"></md-checkbox>` I revised my question a bit to clarify what I'm trying to achieve.